# Replace each element equal to zero of a matrix with the corresponding element of the row above

Tags: r, matrix, data-analysis, data-manipulation

I'm using R. I have a matrix and I want to replace each element of it equal to zero with the corresponding element of the row above.

For example, I created the following matrix:

```
AA <- matrix(c(1,2,3,1,4,5,1,0,2), ncol=3, nrow=3) 

       [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    1    1    
 [2,]    2    4    0
 [3,]    3    5    2
```

I want to replace 0 with the element AA[1,3].
I would like a function able of doing this for each element of a matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could find the row/column index of elements that are 0 in the matrix ('i1'), then extract the elements that correspond to 1 row above by subtracting one from the `row` index in 'i1' and replace the original value.

```
i1 <- which(!AA, arr.ind=TRUE)
AA[i1] <- AA[cbind(i1[,1]-1,i1[,2])]
```

---

Or a one-liner would be using `na.locf` from `library(zoo)` after changing the '0' to NA

```
library(zoo)
na.locf(replace(AA, !AA, NA))
```

If we code-golf, a more compact option would be

```
na.locf(AA*NA^!AA)
```

Comment: do you think it is also possible doing it with the ifelse function?

Comment: @LucaDibo  It is possible, but I think `ifelse` would be slightly slower when compared to row/column indexing.

Comment: could you please show me also the code with the if else function (even if it is slower then yours)?

Comment: @LucaDibo There is already an `ifelse` solution posted by Josliber.